# Avoid negative lookahead regex in mail spam detection

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, postfix-mta, email-spam

Typical legitimate email "header from" fields look like:

`From: DHL <noreply@dhl.com>`

`From: DHL <legit.sender@noreply.dhl.com>`

while non legitimate email "header from" fields look like:

`From: DHL <fake.sender@somedomain.com>`

I would like to write a regex that matches in case of non legitimate email "header from", that is, if DHL appears after the "From:", then what is inside the <> must end with dhl.com

I came with the following regex using negative lookahead (not sure it's 100% exact but it seems to work):

`^From: DHL <.*@(?!.*dhl\.com>$)`

Now the problem is that my regex engine does NOT support negative lookahead and I'm trying to replace it by an equivalent non capturing group like:

`(?:[^d]|d[^h]|dh[^l]|dhl[^\.]|dhl\.[^c]|dhl\.c[^o]|dhl\.co[[^m])`

without success so far. Any idea ?

And if there is a solution, I would like to support case mixing as well (like DhL.COm).

I am looking for a Postfix solution, ideally one which does not require PCRE.

Comment: Which regex engine *are* you using? If it's Procmail, you probably want multiple conditions. If it's Postfix, I believe you _can_ figure out a way to use PCRE regex.

Comment: If you can invert the condition, then `^From: DHL <.*dhl.com>$` could work, and you just say when the regex doesn't match.

Comment: Unfortunately, Zachary Haber, that would match all the non-DHL sourced emails as well.  But if you can create compound conditions then something like ^From: DHL\s AND NOT ^From: DHL <.*dhl.com>$ would do it.

Comment: @tripleee, postfix-pcre would be an option indeed but not possible in my case unfortunately.

Comment: So again, are you looking for a Postfix solution or something else entirely? This affects which precise regex facilities we can use. Please see also the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag guidance](/tags/regex/info) which spells out the requirement to identify the tool or platform you want support for.

Comment: Looking for a Postfix solution without PCRE support. Looks like the next answer is working !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use negative lookahead and you only know what you don't wanna match you would have to test it letter by letter with a lot of | operators

Something like this should work:

```
^From: DHL <.*@.*[^mM]>$|^From: DHL <.*@.*[^oO][mM]>$|^From: DHL <.*@.*[^cC][oO][mM]>$|^From: DHL <.*@.*[^.][cC][oO][mM]>$|^From: DHL <.*@.*[^lL][.][cC][oO][mM]>$|^From: DHL <.*@.*[^hH][lL][.][cC][oO][mM]>$|^From: DHL <.*@.*[^dD][hH][lL][.][cC][oO][mM]$>
```

Comment: This works great. Now I would like to match if what's inside the <> does not end up with either dhl.com or dhl2.org for instance. Tried so many things without success :-( Can you help ?

Comment: @user957479 I don't think it's possible inside a single regex. Best you can do is write another one for the dhl2.org case and then look where you get matches for both case for dhl.com and for dhl2.org. If you try doing it inside a single regex you will inevitably also fail in matching soup of both like dhl.org or dhl2.com or even dhl.oog or other mix of letters from both combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, writing two regex will no work for me. If sender uses dhl2.org, then the first regex (with dhl.com) will match and the user mail will be rejected without interpreting the second regex so no real solution using simple regex here I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think this suits the requirement.

```
(?<=^From: DHL <).*dhl\.com(?=>$)
```

just change:

```
^From: DHL
```

and match it with

```
.*dhl\.com
```

and a little more generalized in the domain sector:

```
(?<=^From: DHL <).*dhl\.([a-zA-Z]{1,3})(?=>$)
```